# How to update the value JSON in localStorage?

Tags: javascript

In localStorage, the key "counters" contains JSON with an object whose fields are the names of the counters, and the values are the numerical value of the counter. incrementCounter function, to which counterName, the name of the counter, is passed as the first parameter to the input. 
How to increase counterName counter by 1 and update data in localStorage?

My code:

```
function incrementCounter(counterName){
  let counters = JSON.parse(localStorage.counters);
  let values = Object.entries(counters);
  for(let [counterName, value] of values){
    return (`${counterName}: ${value+1}`);
  }
  localStorage.setItem("counters", JSON.stringify(values);
}
```

Comment: Don't return from `for .. of` loop, it breaks the execution of the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are looking for something like this:

1. Fetch the counter object from local storage
2. Update the counter property with the counterName
3. If it doesn't exist, set the value to 1
4. Save back to localstorage

.

```
function incrementCounter(counterName){
  const counters = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('counters') || '{}');
  counters[counterName] = (counters[counterName] || 0) + 1;
  localStorage.setItem('counters', JSON.stringify(counters));
}
```

[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/wubtka59/).

Comment: It works the same way. The value changes, but not in the localStorage

Comment: It does change in the local storage..I'll edit and add an example..